# Wordpress in xampp cannot upload images

Tags: windows, wordpress, xampp

I am using XAMPP to work on my wordpress project. I cannot upload images. Images get uploaded in the upload folder but wordpress shows an ERROR, telling me

> There was a mistake while uploading. Try it later.

My XAMPP is installed in `Win7` on partition `C:`. The folders all have under properties:
`"read only applies to files in folder"`

What can i do to upload image?

Comment: `image upload is not possible at the moment` is the only error you get?

Comment: yes! I have another language, but is says exactly that.

Comment: Did you try this [solution](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/images-not-uploading-1)

Comment: I think for the current wordpress there is no "Miscellaneous" under settings and I cannot change the adress of the upload folder

Comment: He means `Dashboard > Settings > Media` uncheck the last option.

Comment: I did uncheck it. But there is still the mistake, although all uploaded files are in the upload folder.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress need write permissions to uplaod images, you need to change the uploads folder permission to 775 ie : read & write for owner & group.

If you are working locally consider to put all your folders permission to 777 (read, write, execute) for all the wp-content it will be easier to develop and maintain.

Comment: All the uploaded files are in the upload folder, but wordpress fires an upload mistake. How can I change the write permissions in Win 7?

Comment: You can try the regular permissions on Windows by right clicking on the uploads folder and using the permissions there, setting to read&write.

Comment: Also make sure your path is correct for uploads. You can find it in the database options, upload_path or upload_path on the wp-admin/options.php page.